# Animating an Image from Opaque to Translucent (And keeping it translucent)

Tags: android, animation

I have an image which I want to slowly fade from opaque to translucent. I've mostly achieved it by looking at [Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html):

layout:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/swipeImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/one_finger_swipe" />
```

Activity:

```
    ImageView swipeImage = (ImageView) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.swipeImage);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
    swipeImage.startAnimation(animation);
```

res/anim/fadeout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shareInterpolator="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0"
            android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="2000"/>   
</set>
```

As I said, I've mostly achieved this because the image does indeed fade. However after the Animation is complete is returns to being opaque. How do I make it stay translucent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `animation.setFillAfter(true)`

`android:fillAfter` can also be used in XML.